# Logstash shipper & server on the samebox

Tags: syslog, logstash

I'm trying to setup a central logstash configuration. However I would like to be sending my logs through syslog-ng and not third party shippers. This means that my logstash server is accepting via syslog-ng all the logs from the agents.

I then need to install a logstash process that will be reading from /var/log/syslog-clients/* and grabbing all the log files that are sent to the central log server. These logs will then be sent to redis on the same VM.

In theory I need to also configure a second logstash process that will read from redis and start indexing the logs and send them to elasticsearch.

My question:

Do I have to use two different logstash processes (shipper & server) even if I am in the same box (I want one log server instance)? Is there any way to just have one logstash configuration and have the process read from syslog-ng ---> write to redis and also read from redis ---> output to elastic search ?

Diagram of my setup:

[client]-------syslog-ng---> [log server] ---syslog-ng <----logstash-shipper ---> redis <----logstash-server ----> elastic-search <--- kibana

Comment: Why are you writing to redis if everything is already on the same server?

Comment: Your setup only needs to be:
`[client]-------syslog-ng---> [log server] ---syslog-ng <----logstash ----> elastic-search <--- kibana`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, but I do know that Syslog-NG can ship directly to Logstash without the need for an additional shipper as an intermediary. You could define a destination in syslog-ng.conf similar to this example:

```
destination d_logstash { 
  tcp("10.0.0.1" port(5514)); 
};
```

And then define a log action to send Syslog messages from `source s_src` to `destination`:

```
log {
  source(s_src);
  destination(d_logstash);
};
```

Which should enable the message transmission. Don't forget to restart the syslog-ng service to apply the changes.

source: The Logstash Book